# JBOSS deployment warning - contains CDI annotations but beans.xml was not found

Tags: java, spring, jboss

I am getting this warning when I start my JBOSS server 7.0.0.. after deploying the my EAR file. I am using Spring 4.1, Hibernate 4

> 16:44:09,254 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1)
>   JBAS016012: Deployment deployment "ExampleService.ear" contains CDI
>   annotations but beans.xml was not found.

Kindly let me know how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 5):

If you want Spring manage your beans, as opposed to the [JBoss' support](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/configure.html) for [Java EE 6 CDI](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giwhl.html), you can safely ignore this warning. Spring will happily scan the classpath for `javax.inject.*` annotations and configure your application accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The bean archive descriptor `beans.xml` should be located at **META-INF/beans.xml** or **WEB-INF/beans.xml**.[more information about CDI](http://www.cdi-spec.org/faq/)